# Пропущенные значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, nan

Есть возможность посмотреть количество пропущенных значений в каждом признаке(столбце):

```
df.isna().sum()
```

[image: Вот такой нужен конечный результат, только с признаками, в которых есть nan]

Но это дает нам перечень всех столбцов. Как вывести только те столбцы(с количеством пропущенных значений), у которых есть пропущенные значения?
Можно конечно сделать что-то вроде:

```
na_feat = [i for i in train.columns if train[i].isna().sum() != 0]    
for i in na_feat:
    print(i, train[i].isna().sum())
```

Но я делал это просто в одну строку и к сожалению забыл как именно(Фэйл!).

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1:

```
In [154]: df.isna().sum().to_frame(name="nans").query("nans > 0")["nans"]
Out[154]: 
b    1
c    3
Name: nans, dtype: int64
```

Вариант 2:

```
In [153]: df.loc[:, df.columns[df.isna().any()]].isna().sum()
Out[153]: 
b    1
c    3
dtype: int64
```

PS первый вариант более производительный потому, что только один раз вызывает `df.isna()` - это самая медленная операция и на больших фреймах разница может быть заметной.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но это создает фрейм... цель в другом. И бесит, что я это делал и напрочь не могу вспомнить как это сделать сейчас. Должно работать в обычном выводе. Добавил фото к описанию

Comment: `res["nans"]`???

Comment: Есть гораздо проще решение, но и оно не идеально: `train.isnull().sum()[train.isna().sum() > 0]`

Comment: Проще - не значит лучше! Это очень похоже на мой второй вариант. Обратите внимание на комментарий PS под ответом

Comment: В любом случае спасибо!